# Read .SMS files in VB Program

Tags: vb.net

I need to read .SMS files from my VB program.
However, I've tried Streamreader and it does not work, it only works with .txt files.

Is there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: The StreamReader works best for _plain text files_. The extension doesn't matter. Would you mind sharing us some background info? For instance where the .SMS-file comes from? And is it readable in Notepad?

Comment: Yes it is readable in the notepad, but the an error will occur if streamreader tries to open a .sms file. The file is just plain text.

Comment: Then what is the error?? Edit the question and show your attempts (=code) and any errors related to it, and **be specific**. You currently provide us with minimal information, with which we won't be able to help you because we've not got enough to go on. I also suggest you, if you haven't already, read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).